# Maximum temperature of plasma according to $pT$ diagram

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, plasma-physics, phase-diagram

When I look at the graph, I can find maximum temperature of plasma (roughly 1eV at 10kPa). But you can get a lot hotter with plasma. Please, where is the mistake?

[image]

See:  or See: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Schematic-of-the-electron-and-gas-temperature-as-a-function-of-pressure-in-a-plasma_fig1_3164388 or https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Plot-of-electron-temperature-T-e-and-gas-temperature-T-g-vs-pressure-where-the_fig5_330738430

Graph:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your response! You can divide plasma into low temperature and high temperature plasma. The low temperature plasma can be then divided into thermal and non Thermal plasma (depicted in the graph). But how would such graph look for high temperature plasma (used in tokamaks/stellarator)? Whz cannot I see it on the graph?

Comment: @Maran_Atha - Plasmas in space are typically much much hotter than $10^{5}$ K (e.g., often >100 eV) and can get to extremely high temperatures (i.e., >1 MeV) in some regions.  The "upper limit" will likely be determined by electron radiative losses in the most extreme environments but I would have to think about this more...

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Indeed, of you take into account Proton number of heaviest elements (<100),  1.36*100^2, just to reach fully ionized plasma you would need 10 KeV. I just wonder how this graph applies to plasma... See: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Plot-of-electron-temperature-T-e-and-gas-temperature-T-g-vs-pressure-where-the_fig5_330738430      or. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Schematic-of-the-electron-and-gas-temperature-as-a-function-of-pressure-in-a-plasma_fig1_3164388

Answer (score 0):

What a foolish mistake! I think I am reading the graph in a wrong manner. The function doesn't show maximum temperature of plasma, but maximum temperature of gas and minimum temperature of  plasma. I believe it has the same meaning as cooling curve in regular pT diagram. Thank you very much for all your response and if I am still not quite right, please correct me.